# How to convert non key, value java arguments to applet params? (args like -Xmx64m)

Tags: java, xenserver, vnc

I'm trying to use xvpviewer (based on TightVNC) to VNC into my VMs running on Citirx XenServer. There are a couple of caveats required with trusting the certificate from XenServer which I've got working.  Essentially I'm trying to convert the java command below (which works on the command line to launch VncViewer) for use in an applet that can be accessed via HTML page.

```
java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/tmp/kimo.jks -Xmx64m -jar VncViewer.jar HOST "/console?ref=OpaqueRef:141f4204-2240-4627-69c6-a0c7d9898e6a&session_id=OpaqueRef:91a483c4-bc40-3bb0-121c-93f2f89acc3c" PORT 443 PROXYHOST1 192.168.0.5 PROXYPORT1 443 SocketFactory "HTTPSConnectSocketFactory"
```

I know I can put the HOST, PORT etc arguments into param tags for the applet but I'm not sure how to apply the two initial argments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out you need the "java_arguments" param used like this:

```
<PARAM name="java_arguments" value="-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/tmp/kimo.jks -Xmx64m">
```

Now my applets running but i'm getting a Network Error: access denied.  But that's another issue.